# How do I use @mention in textAngular directive in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, textangular, mention

I'm using [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) Wysiwyg/Text-Editor, I'm trying to add @mention library to below code, I'm not sure how do I use two directive in same div:

```
text-angular-toolbar class="toolbar button-toolbar" name="workingOn" ta-toolbar="[['h3','h4','p','quote'],['bold','italics', 'underline', 'undo','redo' ],['ul', 'ol','indent', 'outdent', 'insertLink']]"
```

Comment: There is a plunkr demo available here that has the plugin enabled. Maybe it helps. http://embed.plnkr.co/aWBXtk4a5mCNWZFEebiP/  Not sure though, what you mean with the `div` and directive and how this (or the `text-angular-toolar`) is related to the mention plugin.

Comment: Thanks Mathias :) text-angular-toolbar is directive of  textAngular library and mentio is directive of  @Mention directive. May be this plunkr would be useful.